# Паттерн команда при проектировании web приложения. PRG

Tags: java, servlet

Пишу небольшое приложение servlets и jsp. В основе своей оно использует паттерн комманда в таком виде:

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2423353715955164816L;

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class);

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request, response);
}

/**
 * Main method of this controller.
 */
private void process(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    log.debug("Controller starts");

    // extract command name from the request
    String commandName = request.getParameter("command");
    log.trace("Request parameter: command --> " + commandName);

    // obtain command object by its name
    Command command = CommandContainer.get(commandName);
    log.trace("Obtained command --> " + command);

    // execute command and get forward address
    String forward = command.execute(request, response);
    log.trace("Forward address --> " + forward);

    log.debug("Controller finished, now go to forward address --> " + forward);

    // if the forward address is not null go to the address
    if (forward != null) {
        RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        disp.forward(request, response);
    }
}}
```

Те команды которые отображают содержимое возвращают свой результат в таком виде:

```
return Path.PAGE__NON_AUTORIZED_USER_EXPOSITIONS;
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем - как используя паттерн комманда реализовать PRG(POST REDIRECT GET) если те команды которые создают сущности(Post запросом) должны делать sendRedirect на указанную jsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Главное, что нужно сделать, это иметь возможность в `process` определить, что за результат вернула команда и в зависимости от этого возвращать результат по разному.

Как именно это делать - это уже дело вкуса. Вот несколько вариантов.

### Форматированная строка

Подобное делает `spring`. Вместо `Path.PAGE__NON_AUTORIZED_USER_EXPOSITIONS` возвращайте `"forward:" + Path.PAGE__NON_AUTORIZED_USER_EXPOSITIONS` (для случая редиректа `"redirect:" + url)`. `process` должен в зависимости от префикса делать либо `forward` либо редирект.

Удобно сделать вспомогательные функции:

```
public String forward(String to) {
   return String.format("forward:%s", to);
}
public String redirect(String to) {
   return String.format("redirect:%s", to);
}
```

чтобы в команде можно было писать:

```
return forward( Path.PAGE__NON_AUTORIZED_USER_EXPOSITIONS);
```

### Типизированный результат

Вместо `String` возвращать объект своего класса.

```
interface CommandResult {
   String getResource();
}

class ForwardResult implements CommandResult {
  private String forwardResource;
  public ForwardResource(String resource) {
    this.forwardResource = resource;
  }
  public String getResource() {
    return forwardResource;
  }
}

class RedirectResult implements CommandResult {
  public String getResource() {
  }
}
```

`process` в зависимости от типа делает то, что нужно.

```
interface View {
 void render(CommandResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response);
}

class Controller {

  private static Map<Class<?>, View> views = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    views.put(ForwardResult.class, (result, request, response) -> {
      RequestDispatcher disp =
          request.getRequestDispatcher(result.getResource());
      disp.forward(request, response);
    });
    views.put(RedirectResult.class, (result, request, response) -> {
      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + result.getResource());
   });
  }

  void process(...) {
    ...
    Command command = CommandContainer.get(commandName);
  
    CommandResult result = command.execute(request, response);
  
    views.get(result.getClass()).render(result, request, response);
  }
}
```

В этом случае команда должна возвращать результат как-то так:

```
return new ForwardResult(Path.PAGE__NON_AUTORIZED_USER_EXPOSITIONS);
```

Comment: я еще хотел у Вас спросить - какое наполнение метода getResource() класса ForwardResult и RedirectResult - для примера - мне больше нравиться 2 ой вариант - конечно же!!

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!!!!

Comment: Роман, я очень извиняюсь - но я начинающий не могли бы вы мне еще на такой вопрос ответить - 
<code>
      Map<Class<?>, View> views = ImmutableMap.of(
   ForwardResult.class, (result, request, response) -> {
      RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher(result.getResource());
      disp.forward(request, response);
    }
   },
   RedirectResult.class, (result, request, response) -> {
      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + result.getResource());
   }
);
</code> должен быть в методе render моей вью?

Comment: Да я вью так и объявил.А сам метод - render - я так понимаю - вы написали его содержимое - но я не могу понять - как мне его использовать - еще вопрос - могу ли я ImmutableMap заменить на HashMap?

Comment: Я изменил код, чтобы он использовал `HashMap` и статический блок инициализации вместо `ImmutableMap`, надеюсь так будет понятней.

Comment: Спасибо, Роман!